# how could I interpret 後に in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

So I've been reading the script from a videogame and I have a problem with this sentence:

> ダークエルフによるレプリロイドの支配とイレギュラーの抹殺…**後に**妖精戦争と呼ばれる争いを起こしたワシは、

I don't quite get it what 後に means in this sentences, I don't think it means "after" or "later" as I thought at first because in the next sentence it mentions what happens after after the war ends:

> 妖精戦争が終わった時に、当時の人間どもの手である改造を施された。

According to the translation I've been reading, the 後に part has is saying something like: "After all it was me who started the war called...".

So, what is the meaning of 後に?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ［後に妖精戦争と呼ばれる］争い

The [後]{のち}に modifies 呼ばれる. 後に妖精戦争と呼ばれる is a relative clause modifying 争い.

"A conflict [later called 妖精戦争]"

Comment: wow, I never thought  後に was acting as an atribute, I thought it was a conjunctive or part of former sentence, now it makes sense